# Formula Master Therorem

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

How can I formulate a master theorem (without giving a formal proof) that identifies these three cases:

1. $T(n) = \Theta(n)$
2. $T(n) = \Theta(n\log(n))$
3. $T(n) = \Theta(n^x)$

Comment: What is $T$ in this context?

Comment: Running time....